# Computer Science: regular languages

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

Is it possible to prove with pumping lemma that the languge
$$L=\{w_1w_2 \mid w_1,w_2\in\{a,b,c\}^* \text{ and } \#_a(w_1)>\#_b(w_1) \text{ and } \#_b(w_2)>\#_c(w_2)\}$$
(where $\#_x(w)$ is the number of the letter $x$ in $w$) is not regular.

Using Myhill-Nerode, we could simply say for $k>0: [a_k]=\{a^k\}$ would describe an equivalence class, they are all disjoint pairwise, because i could say: $(i,j ≥ 1) \wedge (i>j) \implies (a^ib^i ∈ L) \wedge (a^{i-1}b^j ∉ L)$

Comment: Please keep all of your equations in MathJax, as it is much easier to read!

Comment: I am sorry, I changed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the pumping lemma works just fine. Given pumping length $k$, pick the word $b^ka^{k+1}c^{4k}b$. This pattern gives us control over which part of the word is $w_1$, namely everything but the final $b$.

Now, any decomposition $uvw = b^ka^{k+1}c^{4k}b$ with $|uv| \leq k$ and $|v| > 0$ means that $v$ consists of between $1$ and $k$ many $b$'s, say $\ell$. Now $uv^2w = b^{k+\ell}a^{k+1}c^{4k}b$. If this word would belong to the language, then $w_2$ could only be $b$ - anything longer has too many $c$'s in it. But $b^{k+\ell}a^{k+1}c^{4k}$ doesn't have more $a$'s than $b$'s, so it can't be $w_1$ either. We conclude that $b^{k+\ell}a^{k+1}c^{4k}b$ doesn't belong to the language, and thus the pumping lemma tells us that it is not regular.

Comment: I got a similar idea, but the problem is, that $v$ does not consist in every decomposition out of b's. It can have only b's, but it can also consist out of only a's. For these two options the lemma works. 
But it can also only be c's, in this case no matter what you choose for $uv^lw$ you can only pump the c's and then you can divide the word into $w_1$  and $w_2$. 
$v$ can also consist of b's and a's, a's and c's and c's and one b.
The problem here is, if it consists of a's and b's and and the number of a's in v is the same as the number of b's, than the lemma also doesn't work.

Comment: @schegga_B You are mistaken. The $v$-part must be within the first $k$ symbols, and there are only $b$'s there. Thus, $v$ consists only of $b$'s. No other case possible.

Comment: I am sorry, you are completely right. I was getting confused with the pumping lemma for context-free languages. There you have to consider such things... 
Thank you!